# How to display errors for product imports

Tags: magento2, import, magento2.2

When I import product using the Import functionality in Magento (2.2.1), I sometimes get an error saying "Maximum error count has been reached or system error is occurred!".

According to the Magento website and some online tutorials, I should see a link to view all errors that were generated, but all I see is this message being displayed, which is very generic.

I don't see any settings that prevent the errors from showing. Also, raising the maximum error count in the import settings doesn't seem to do anything. How can I check the errors?

Comment: i have also same error found while we importing 7th file. first 6 file has no any error found after 7th file error has display [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuRh6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuRh6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this issue was fixed in the latest version of Magento. After an upgrade to Magento version 2.2.2, I see the error report as expected:

[image: error]

Answer (score 2):

Previously, Magento had problems with url rewrites and you could quickly reach the maximum error count and cause import failure. Generally, to avoid this problem during product import it is necessary to keep to main recommendations:

- save file with utf-8 encoding
- include proper columns and data
  delimiters
- make sure you included all the required fields in correct format.